# Copy and rename only latest files with python

Tags: python, batch-rename

I want to copy some files with renaming them

where in the first element: `src/` is a directory, `357` is the ID, `1329844313` is the timestamp, `.jpg` is file extension.

now I want to have list as following:
(destination directory) + (SALT) + '_' + (ID) + (extension)
as my salt is: '423l4kj2342'
my expected result will be:

```
    dest/423l4kj2342_357.jpg
```

My renaming functionality is as expected.

```
src/picture-357-1329844313.jpg  dest/423l4kj2342_357.jpg
src/picture-57-1329844816.png   dest/423l4kj2342_57.png
src/picture-358-1329844317.jpg  dest/423l4kj2342_358.jpg
src/picture-57-1329844814.jpg   dest/423l4kj2342_57.jpg
src/picture-358-1329844313.jpg  dest/423l4kj2342_358.jpg
src/picture-358-1329844325.jpg  dest/423l4kj2342_358.jpg
```

However, the files are overwriting which have same ID. I want only the latest files where same ID exists.

Now my question is, how can I get the following result? copying same ID files containing only the latest timestamps?

```
src/picture-357-1329844313.jpg  dest/423l4kj2342_357.jpg
src/picture-57-1329844816.png   dest/423l4kj2342_57.png
src/picture-358-1329844325.jpg  dest/423l4kj2342_358.jpg
```

Comment: Please bring your problem down to the real point. It does not help providing page-long blather and code without clearly stating your problem.

Comment: I have updated my question. sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Sort your file list by ID and timestamp lexicographically descending, then for each ID only process the first one.

Something like the following:

```
def cmp_file(a, b):
  id_a, timestamp_a = re.findall(r'\d+', a)
  id_b, timestamp_b = re.findall(r'\d+', b)
  return 2*cmp(id_a, id_b) + cmp(timestamp_a, timestamp_b)

filelist.sort(cmp=cmp_file, reverse=True)

last_id = None
for file in filelist:
  id, timestamp = re.findall(r'\d+',file)
  if not last_id == id:
    process_file(file)
    last_id = id
```

Or alternatively, put your filenames in an ID indexed dict of lists of tuples of timestamps and filenames. Then for each dict entry find the one with the maximum timestamp and process that file:

```
index = dict()
for file in filelist:
  id, timestamp = re.findall(r'\d+',file)
  if not id in index:
    index[id] = list()
  index[id].append((timestamp, file))
for id, files in index.iteritems():
  process_file(files.max(key=lambda a: a[0])[1])
```